# SwiftUI - Core-Data - Access to wrapped value in this kind of special case

Tags: macos, core-data, swiftui

With the following code (see CODE below), I get this kind of result (see RESULT below):
Starting with the code shown below (without using a view ...), how can I access the WrappedValues instead of this kind of result ?

Thanks for helping!

RESULT:

```
<Translation: 0x600002132440> (entity: Translation; id: 0x6742c7fbe17c81d1 <x-coredata://0B558EF2-1CC5-4649-9D70-560DAA900FFE/Translation/p21>; data: {
    id = 11;
    language = English;
    wording = "Select the Folders to Rename...";
})
```

CODE:

```
class FetchWording: ObservableObject {
    func fetch (pID: String) -> String {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Translation")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", pID as CVarArg), NSPredicate(format: "language == %@", sDisplayLanguage as CVarArg)])
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
         do {
            let fetchWording = try ContentView().managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print (fetchWording[0])
         } catch {
             print ("Error")
         }
        return (“See you later when it’s working”)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

…Just find this, not very satisfying:

```
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Translation")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", pID as CVarArg), NSPredicate(format: "language == %@", sDisplayLanguage as CVarArg)])
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    var fetchWording = [NSManagedObject]()
    do {
        let records = try ContentView().managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        if let records = records as? [NSManagedObject] {
            fetchWording = records
        }
        return **fetchWording.first!.value(forKey: "wording")! as! String**
    } catch {
        print ("Unexpected error: Function fetch: Wording not found!")
    }
```